# how can I switch form for loop to while loop in c?

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to replace my 'for' loop with a 'while' loop but I get a different output.

**The for loop:**

```
    for(int row = mlx->shot->height - 1; row >= 0; row--)
    {
        y = 0;
        for(int col = 0; col < mlx->shot->width; col++)
        {

            int red = (mlx->tex.img_data[x * w + y] >> 16) & 0xFF;
            int green = (mlx->tex.img_data[x * w + y] >> 8) & 0xFF;
            int blue = mlx->tex.img_data[x * w + y] & 0xFF;
 
 
            buf[row * mlx->shot->width_in_bytes + col * 3 + 0] = blue;
            buf[row * mlx->shot->width_in_bytes + col * 3 + 1] = green;
            buf[row * mlx->shot->width_in_bytes + col * 3 + 2] = red;
            y++;
        }
        x++;
     }
```

here The output is perfect

**My while loop:**

```
    int row;

    row = mlx->shot->height - 1;
    while (row >= 0)
    {
        y = 0;
        col = 0;
        while (col < mlx->shot->width)
        {
            int red = (mlx->tex.img_data[x * w + y] >> 16) & 0xFF;
            int green = (mlx->tex.img_data[x * w + y] >> 8) & 0xFF;
            int blue = mlx->tex.img_data[x * w + y] & 0xFF;
            buf[row * mlx->shot->width_in_bytes + col * 3 + 0] = blue;
            buf[row * mlx->shot->width_in_bytes + col * 3 + 1] = green;
            buf[row * mlx->shot->width_in_bytes + col * 3 + 2] = red;
            col++;
            y++;
        }
        row--;
        x++;
     }
```

But here I get an: `1163 segmentation fault`

EDIT: The rest of The variables is already declared.
This is The hole Function:

```
void                screno(t_mlx *mlx)
{
    int x ;
    int y ;
    int row;
    int col;

    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    row = mlx->shot->height - 1;
    col = 0;
    unsigned char* buf = malloc(mlx->shot->imagesize);
    while (row >= 0)
    {
        y = 0;
        col = 0;
        while (col < mlx->shot->width)
        {
            int red = (mlx->tex.img_data[x * w + y] >> 16) & 0xFF;
            int green = (mlx->tex.img_data[x * w + y] >> 8) & 0xFF;
            int blue = mlx->tex.img_data[x * w + y] & 0xFF;
            buf[row * mlx->shot->width_in_bytes + col * 3 + 0] = blue;
            buf[row * mlx->shot->width_in_bytes + col * 3 + 1] = green;
            buf[row * mlx->shot->width_in_bytes + col * 3 + 2] = red;
            col++;
            y++;
        }
        row--;
        x++;
    }
    /*for(int row = mlx->shot->height - 1; row >= 0; row--)
    {
        y = 0;
        for(int col = 0; col < mlx->shot->width; col++)
        {

            int red = (mlx->tex.img_data[x * w + y] >> 16) & 0xFF;
            int green = (mlx->tex.img_data[x * w + y] >> 8) & 0xFF;
            int blue = mlx->tex.img_data[x * w + y] & 0xFF;
 
 
            buf[row * mlx->shot->width_in_bytes + col * 3 + 0] = blue;
            buf[row * mlx->shot->width_in_bytes + col * 3 + 1] = green;
            buf[row * mlx->shot->width_in_bytes + col * 3 + 2] = red;
            y++;
        }
        x++;
    }*/
    ft_printf("Taking ScreenShoot....\n");
    FILE *fout = fopen("screenshot.bmp", "wb");
    ft_printf("ScreenShot Has been saved under The name 'screenshot.bmp']\n");
    fwrite(mlx->shot->header, 1, 54, fout);
    fwrite((char*)buf, 1, mlx->shot->imagesize, fout);
    fclose(fout);
    free(buf);
}
```

when I use the for loop The code work perfectly fine.
but with the while loop, I get an error or The image saved empty.

Comment: `int row;` -> `int row = mlx->shot->height - 1;`. In your code you never initialize `row`.

Comment: But anyway, the version with `for` is better style, there is no reason to replace the for loop with a while loop.

Comment: I have to replace it with a while loop because in The subject of the project for loops is forbidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable you want to use in while loop is to be initialized first and then you can use it in the while loop and write the body of your loop then decrement/increment the variable accordingly.

While loop format

```
initialization; 
while(condition) 
{ 
body 
decrement/increment variable 
}
```

The variable you want to use in the for loop can be initialized  in the loop itself.

For loop format

```
for(initialization;condition;decrement/increment)
{ 
body 
}
```

You have just declared the variable you haven't initialized it.
Just change  `int row;` to
`int row = mlx->shot->height - 1;`

Comment: _decrement/increment_ is a special case, you can do anything you want lik for example : `p = p->next` or even nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the following line at the beginning:

```
int row = mlx->shot->height - 1;
```

you should check for zero values before looping

Comment: @The Night King, That and the missing declaration of `col` are the only differences. If you have having a problem with these fixes, the problem is elsewhere; it has nothing to do with your choice of loop.

Comment: I started thinking that the problem is somewhere else. I will check my code again. Thank You @ikegami

Comment: @DarkSide77, Make sure to always enable warnings (e.g. you could use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` with `gcc`/`clang`). Also, `-fsanitize=addresss` could be of use to help track down the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In this code you don't initialize `row`. Just declaring a variable leaves the variable with an indetermined content, possibly a very big number and when you use it as an array index like in `buf[row * mlx->shot->width_in_bytes + col * 3 + 0]`, you're accessing the array out of bounds which is undefined behaviour and often results in a segmentation fault.

```
int row;          
while (row >= 0)  // row contains an indetermined value here
```

You need this:

```
int row = mlx->shot->height - 1;
while (row >= 0)
```

Generally spoken a for loop is just more or less syntactic sugar for a while loop:

```
for (x;y;z)
{
  ...  
}
```

is more or less equivalent to:

```
x;
while (y)
{
  ...  
  z;
}
```